# Alternate fields in HTTP POST request body

Tags: rest, http, swagger

I've been looking for the best way to specify a body type for an HTTP POST request that has two fields that are mutually exclusive.
I'm using swagger for the API specification, and I have one request that must have either field_A or field_B, but not both.

Right now I am setting both fields as optional, describing the behaviour in the spec (when to set one field or the other), and validating the input on the server. If none of the fields is filled I am returning a 400-Bad-request.

My question is whether or not this is the correct approach (would it be more RESTful if I specify an extra content-type?), or if there is something in Swagger that allows me to make this behaviour more obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across an API that solved my issue.
For a given field, the type for that field is extensible (like a base class, and multiple extending classes). To distinguish between the different sub-types there is a discriminator field.

For example (YAML in swagger format), type Foo is extensible and has subtypes FooA and FooB. The discriminator is a type field:

```
definitions:
  Foo:
    type: object
    properties:
      type: string
      x-extensible-enum:
        - FOO_A
        - FOO_B
      discriminator: type
      required:
        - type
  FOO_A:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
      - type: object
        properties:
          field_a:
            type: string
        required:
          - field_a
  FOO_B:
    allOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/Foo'
      - type: object
        properties:
          field_b:
            type: integer
            format: int32
        required:
          - field_b
```

This makes deserialisation more complex, but it's a quite interesting approach and very flexible.